# A get or set accessor is expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playercombat : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Animator animator;
    public Transform attackPoint;
    public float attackRange = 0.5f;
    public LayerMask enemyLayers;

    public float AttackRange { get => attackRange; 0.5f => attackRange = 0.5f; }
   

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            Attack();
        }
    }
    void Attack()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Attack");

        Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPoint.postion, AttackRange, enemyLayers);

        foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies) 
        {
            Debug.lot("Hit" + enemy.name);
        }
    }
    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        if (attackPoint == null)
            return;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(attackPoint.position, AttackRange);
    }
}
```

A get or set accesssor expected. What does that mean and how should I fix it?
Assets\playercombat.cs(13,52): error CS1014: A get or set accessor expected
Assets\playercombat.cs(13,60): error CS1014: A get or set accessor expected

Comment: Why do you have both "public float attackRange" and "public float AttackRange"? It would make more sense to only have one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setter on AttackRange is weird. KYL3R's answer implies that you want to set attackRange to 0.5f whenever you set it, no matter what you set it to. That seems equally weird. I think you want

```
public float AttackRange { get => attackRange; set => attackRange = value; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Typo?

```
public float AttackRange { get => attackRange; 0.5f => attackRange = 0.5f; }
```

should be

```
public float AttackRange { get => attackRange; set => attackRange = 0.5f; }
```

Comment: What would `set => attackRange = 0.5f;` supposed to do though? I guess you would rather want `set => attackRange = value;` ^^

Comment: ` = value` is very likely what OP wanted, yes. Though I tried to help fix OP's error while changing the semantic as little as possible. But yes, it doesn't hurt to mention the setter would be useless like this.

Answer (score 0):

on line 12 you have a typo,:

```
public float AttackRange { get => attackRange; 0.5f => attackRange = 0.5f; }
```

You might want to modify it to:

```
public float AttackRange { get {return attackRange;}  set { attackRange = value; }}
```

or

```
  public float AttackRange { get; set; }
```

Comment: No, you either have an auto-implemented property `public float AttackRange { get; set; }` **or** one with backing field `public float AttackRange { get => attackRange; set => attackRange = 0.5f;}` .. you ca't have a mix of both and OP apparently wants to do something with `attackRange`

Comment: @derHugo sure, you are right. But it's a  small discrepancy. I was only trying to point out the typo.